# Xen: Can't ping from domU to dom0

Tags: networking, xen, bridge, hypervisor

I have 2 local connected PCs. I'v created 2 VMs on PC1 and added connection through bridging using eth0 interface in dom0.

```
From dom0: 

#brctl addbr xenbr0
#brctl addif xenbr0 eth0
#ifconfig xenbr0 10.0.2.4
#xl create /etc/xen/dom1.cfg
#xl create /etc/xen/dom2.cfg

#ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0A:35:00:22:01
          inet addr:10.0.2.1  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20a:35ff:fe00:2201/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:36193 (35.3 KiB)  TX bytes:407300 (397.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:25

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:560 (560.0 B)  TX bytes:560 (560.0 B)

vif2.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
          RX bytes:2524 (2.4 KiB)  TX bytes:2558 (2.4 KiB)

vif3.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
          RX bytes:1212 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1165 (1.1 KiB)

xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0A:35:00:22:01
          inet addr:10.0.2.3  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20a:35ff:fe00:2201/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4224 (4.1 KiB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)
```

In the Xen cfg files I have this line "vif = [ 'script=vif-bridge, bridge=xenbr0' ]"

From domU

```
#ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3E:60:FC:91
          inet addr:10.0.2.6  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:23886 (23.3 KiB)  TX bytes:22500 (21.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

After booting to guest VMs I have the following ping statuses:

- Ping between domUs is OK.
- Ping between domUs and PC2 is OK.
- Ping from domU to dom0(PC1) is not OK!

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Change `vif = [ 'script=vif-bridge, ridge=xenbr0' ]` to `vif = [ 'script=vif-bridge, bridge=xenbr0' ]`, you lost a b

Comment: consider upgrading your comment to an answer, @Broco

Comment: @asdmin I would but I don't know if this was just a typo in his post or the actual cause of the problem

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Comment: Also tried to ping using differ IPs for the eth0 and xenbr0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both eth0 and xenbr0 have an IP (it's even the same IP). Get rid of the IP on eth0.  Bridges are layer 2 abstractions, so you can't have layer 3 addressing on interfaces that connect to it. Keep the IP on the bridge interface, as that's the one that you put layer 3 addressing on. This is true of anything you connect to a bridge, including bonds. The end of the layer 2 stack gets the layer 3 address.